# nothing (expecting JSON) returned from server?

Tags: jquery, json

i am trying to experiment with the [tumblr api](http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api). i tried

```
$(function() {
  $.getJSON("http://jiewmeng.tumblr.com/api/read/json", function(data) {
    $("#postsContainer").append(data);
  });
});
```

but got a 200 OK with empty response in firebug. when i navigate to http://jiewmeng.tumblr.com/api/read/json, i see the data. so i shld be getting something rather than a empty response?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have 2 issues, here, for cross-domain requests you need [JSONP, by sticking `callback=?` in the URL](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/), and you need to access some property, like this:  `data.tumblelog.title`.  Here's an example:

```
$(function() {
  $.getJSON("http://jiewmeng.tumblr.com/api/read/json?callback=?", function(data) {
    $("#postsContainer").text(data.tumblelog.title);
  });
});​
```

[You can view a quick demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/kVufQ/), to see what data is available [the API can be found here](http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api#api_read), or view it in your console...or just [visit the URL yourself](http://jiewmeng.tumblr.com/api/read/json) and paste the result into a markup site, like [jsbeautifier.org](http://jsbeautifier.org/) to make it more readable.

Comment: +1 nick... your explanation is correct... I have deleted mine.. ;)

Comment: one question nick, why is the json file starting like `var tumblr_api_read = {"tumblelog":{"title":"Jiew Meng"....` ? why not just `{"tumblelog":{"title":"Jiew Meng"....` ? I'm confused with the `var`...

Comment: @Reigel - Add `?jsoncallback=myFunction` to the URL to see :) JSONP more-or-less by making a script tag that grabs the `src` (so no cross-domain POST, it's a GET, and without headers), jQuery dynamically names your success function, you can see it in the console, and the resulting script is `myMadeUpFunctionName({ object here });`, which just runs that function :)